# The maximum length of a line contained inside a convex polygon

Tags: algorithms

I have a convex polygon. What algorithm do you suggest to find the maximum length of a line with a specific slope that is contained inside the polygon.

- The direction of the line is shown with blue arrow in the image.

[image]

Comment: check only the lines that go through one of the vertices of your polygon, I'm pretty convinced it must be the case

Comment: @mm-aops Thanks, pretty clever idea, any further suggestions on finding the second end point of that line?

Comment: well, dunno, that depends on the way you store your polygone. the other endpoint lays on the boundary of the polygone and so is uniquely determined but finding it numerically is really a question of the specific implementation I guess

Comment: @mm-aops, how to prove that you only need to check vertices? I have a gut feeling that it must be the case, but a proof would be appreciated. ;)

Comment: well, both endpoints must be on the boundary (that's obvious) so imagine they both are on the interior of some two edges. now if the edges are parallel then moving around doesn't change a thing so we can go up to one of the vertices. if they are not then they intersect at some point (if you extend them to be actual lines). now you do a Tales theorem and see, that the closer you move to the intersection point the shorter your line is

Comment: @mm-aops, great. Thanks. I imagined something very close, but my imagination doesn't work too well today. :)

Comment: Thanks mm-aops, wish you had posted this as an answer so I could select it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you only need to check lines that pass through vertices. Suppose the given direction vector is $U$. Then, given a vertex $V$, you (potentially) have to construct a line through $V$ in the direction of $U$, and intersect it with every side of the polygon. This is a fairly expensive $O(n)$ computation, where $n$ denotes the number of sides in the polygon.

But, most of the time, you can avoid this computation. The vertex $V_i$ only needs to be checked if it "contains" the vector $U$. To be more specific, we let $A = V_{i-1} - V_i$ and $B = V_{i+1} - V_i$ be the vectors along the polygon sides emanating from $V_i$. Some simple vector calculations will tell you whether $U$ lies inside the sector bounded by $A$ and $B$. If it doesn't, then you can omit the (expensive) intersection calculations. This gives you an $O(n)$ algorithm, instead of an $O(n^2)$ one.

Comment: Thanks bubba, I still need to find to intersection of endpoint of the `U` vector with the edges right? Let's say I know at least two of them can't be the ones this vector will intersect. (the ones emanating from the other end point). You mean A and B will tell me how to detect the other edges that the U vector doesn't get involved with?

Comment: The $A$ and $B$ vectors, and their relationship to the $U$ vector, will tell you that you don't need to do any intersections at all for this vertex -- you can skip it and proceed to the next vertex.

Comment: Thank you so much bubba, I got it now.